# My non path-specific batch script only works from certain paths… why?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I've made the following batch script:

```
::@ECHO OFF
echo %date% %time%  Starting File Splitter

set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
set second=%time:~6,2%
set folderName=%year%-%month%-%day%-%hour%-%minute%-%second%
set folderName=%folderName: =%
SET logger="%~dp0"\%folderName%.log

cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ctr=0
set name=Startup
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in (pppclient.log) do (
    set inline=%%1
    Echo.!inline! | findstr /C:"Starting PosPay Client... ">nul && (
        set name=Startup
        set /a ctr+=1
    )
    Echo.!inline! | findstr /C:"/purchase ">nul && (
        set name=Purchase
        set /a ctr+=1
    )
    Echo !inline! >>!ctr!_!name!.log
)
```

In the first place this works just as I want it to. However, sometimes when I move\copy-paste the script to a different path, it suddenly does nothing. 
**It will say that no pppclient.log file was found** - but the file is there! Why??

Comment: does the script outputs some errors?What means `not working`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible reasons:

1. You expect perhaps that the current working directory is the directory of the batch file. But the current working directory could be a different one. Add a line with `echo Working directory is: %CD%` to see what is the current working directory on executing the batch file.
2. [Permissions for files and folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787794.aspx) are set to allow listing of the files and subfolders in a folder, but do now allow to read the data in the files.
3. The file **pppclient.log** is opened currently by another application with [CFile::shareExclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz0a83sb.aspx) which means no other application can read from or write to this file as long as the application has it open (for write operations).

Read access to a log file is quite often blocked by the application writing to this log file.

You could find out with free tool [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals (Microsoft) why the log file "could not be found".